# swift subclasses in function types

Tags: swift, function, types

Is there a way to assign a function with a parameter that is a subclass to a function variable with a parameter that is its superclass? Here is an example of what I mean:

```
class ClassA {}

class subclassOfA:ClassA {}

func subclassToNil(argument:subclassOfA) -> (){}

var functionVariable:(ClassA->())

funcVar = subclassToNil
```

This raises a type incompatibility exception.

Comment: That cannot work. `functionVariable()` could be called with an instance of `ClassA`, but the function expects an instance of the *subclass* as parameter. (It would work only the other way around.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid not--you've discovered "covariance" and "contravariance". Function types are contravariant with their parameters (arguments), which means you could supply a *superclass* if you wanted, but not a subclass. With *return values* on the other hand, function types are are covariant and could return a *subclass* if you'd like.

With a little thought, these rules make sense:

```
class ClassA {}

class SubclassOfA: ClassA {}

func subclassToNil(argument: SubclassOfA) -> ()) {}

var functionVariable: (ClassA -> ())

functionVariable = subclassToNil

functionVariable(ClassA()) //`subclassToNil` won't know what to do with this; kablooie!
```

However:

```
class ClassParent {}

class ClassA: ClassParent {}

func subclassToNil(argument: ClassParent) -> ()) {}

var functionVariable:(ClassA -> ())

functionVariable = subclassToNil

functionVariable(ClassA()) //`ClassA()` is indeed a valid `ClassParent`, so we're fine.
```

So it's safe to use parameters that are *less* specific. The reasoning for return values is very similar, and you'll see that logically, you can use ones that are *more* specific.

Comment: That's funny because I had tried an example with the return type as a subclass and as you said, and compiler didn't complain. This example makes it very clear why because setting 'subclassToNil' doesn't change the type signature of functionVariable!